# Horizontal Toggle Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

I'm trying to create a horizontal dropdown (err.. dropside?).

When clicked, it expands to the right to show more options, and the user can click the option they want.

I have found this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj3hj7x8/) but it is implemented using `ul` and `li`, not `select` and `option`.  Does this really matter for the purposes of clicking a menu item and dispatching an action? It also expands on hover, not on click. And when a menu item is clicked, I need the menu to stay open until the 'X' on the left is clicked. If anyone could help me start on this it would be much appreciated.

[Here's an image of what I'm trying to do](https://ibb.co/yqFk7nb)

Comment: Please put here your code to help you.

Comment: Select & Options is normally a form item, not a menu selector. But sometimes the select is used as "page selelctor" with ugly styling. The proper way to create a menu is with an ul list and li items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("item")].forEach(i => i.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this);
}));

document.getElementById("open-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.parentElement.classList.add("open");
});

document.getElementById("close-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.parentElement.classList.remove("open");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.menu {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 17px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .item {
  display: none;
  color: grey;
}
.menu #open-button {
  display: block;
}
.menu #close-button {
  display: none;
  color: grey;
}

.menu.open {
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
}
.menu.open .item {
  display: block;
}
.menu.open .item:hover {
  color: black;
}
.menu.open #close-button {
  display: block;
}
.menu.open #close-button:hover {
  color: black;
}
.menu.open #open-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div id="open-button">Menu</div>
  <div id="close-button">&#10005;</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I am wondering what `this` in `  <div class="open-button" onclick="openMenu(this)">Menu</div>` is supposed to reflect? It comes back as undefined for me

Comment: @N.A `this` is supposed to refer to a clicked html element. Do you get an error saying that `e` is undefined inside of the `openMenu` function? Do you use any framwork or just JS?

Comment: @N.A anyways, if that doesn't work - you could bind those functions using `addEventListener`. Check the updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating. That makes sense, but its still not working... I posted a question with my full code if you have time to take a look. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161809/building-dynamic-menu-with-click-handler

Comment: @N.A well, this question asks for a horizontal toggle, and as you can see, my answer provides it and it works. What doesn't work is your further modification of this code. You are right - it's a topic for a separate question. It looks like you are using react, so it completely changes the context. You should use different techniques to achieve this in react.

Answer (score 1):

if you for some reason have to use select and option in your markup here's how to do it, but it's a lot of work https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

or you can do something like this:

```js
var btnToggle = document.querySelector(".js-toggle");

btnToggle.addEventListener("click", handleMenu);

function handleMenu() {
  var menu = document.querySelector(".js-menu");
  if ( menu.classList.contains("is-showing") )
  {
    menu.classList.remove("is-showing");
  }
  else
  {
    menu.classList.add("is-showing");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}


.navigation {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 22px;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
}
.menu.is-showing {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.menu__item {
  background: #fff;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  background: #999;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 22px;
}
.box:hover {
  background: #498cdf;
}

.toggle {
  padding: 0;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  border: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  
  <button class="toggle js-toggle">x</button>
  <ul class="menu js-menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <span class="box"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<nav>
  <a class="nav-btn">Logo</a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
 a, li {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .expand{
          display: block;
    }
```

```js
$("nav .nav-btn").click(function(){
 
  $("nav ul").toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```css
a, li {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

.expand{
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a class="nav-btn">Logo</a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```