# Building Dynamic Menu With Click Handler

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having lots of trouble finding the issue in this code... I am trying to build a horizontal menu that expands when clicked, the user can then click the option they want. To close the expanded menu, they can click an 'X' on the left. [Here's an image of what I want it to look like](https://ibb.co/yqFk7nb)

I asked a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158580/horizontal-toggle-dropdown) and made some changes but don't know what to do from here.

My main questions:

- How do I add the dynamically created list elements from `buildLanguageSelector`?
- How do I add a click handler to the `menu` and `x` so that they toggle when clicked? Right now, `this` being passed into the click handler is `null`

  ```js
  const LanguageSelector = (props) => {
    const { languages, onSelectLanguage } = props
    const listContainer = document.createElement('ul')
    listContainer.style.position = 'absolute'
    listContainer.style.top = '0'

    const buildLanguageSelector = () => {
      if (props.ui.languages.length) {
        [...props.ui.languages].forEach(function (language, i) {
          const el = document.createElement('li')
          el.value = language.languageCode
          el.innerHTML = language.name
          el.className = "item"
          el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation()
          })
          listContainer.appendChild(el)
        })
      } else {
      }
    }

    buildLanguageSelector()

    const openMenu = (e) => {
      console.log(e)
      e.parentElement.classList.add('open')
    }
    const closeMenu = (e) => {
      e.parentElement.classList.remove('open')
    }

    return (
      <div className='menu'>
        // `this` being passed into `openMenu` and `closeMenu` is null
        <div className='open-button' onClick= {openMenu(this)}>Menu</div>
        <div className='close-button' onClick= {closeMenu(this)}>&#10005;</div>
       // I know that this part is incorrect-- however I'm not sure how 
       // to insert the dynamically created li's from buildLanguageSelector
        <div>{listContainer}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  ```

  ```css
  body {
      background: white;
  }
  .menu {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 17px;
      height: 34px;
      width: 100px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

  .menu .item {
      display: none;
      color: grey;
  }
  .menu #open-button {
      display: block;
  }
  .menu #close-button {
      display: none;
      color: grey;
  }

  .menu.open {
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 300px;
  }
  .menu.open .item {
      display: block;
  }
  .menu.open .item:hover {
      color: black;
  }
  .menu.open .close-button {
      display: block;
  }
  .menu.open .close-button:hover {
      color: black;
  }
  .menu.open .open-button {
      display: none;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Added sample menu implementation

I realize that stylistically this isn't what you're going for, but conceptually this is the direction I think you'd want to go:

```js
const languages = [
  "English",
  "Spanish",
  "French",
  "Wookie",
  "Klingon"
]

function Menu () {
  // keep track of whether the menu is open
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
  // in a real app this would notify interested
  // parties (redux dispatch or whatever)
  const [selectedLanguage, setLanguage] = React.useState(languages[0]); 
  
  // convenience function for setting the language
  // and closing the menu
  const onLangSelect = language => {
setLanguage(language);
setOpen(false);
  };
  
  return (
<div>
  <button onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>{selectedLanguage} v</button>
  <ul className="language-menu">
    {
      // if the menu is open, render the items…
      isOpen && (
        // by iterating over the available languages and emitting an item for each.
        // item.onClick invokes onLangSelect, passing in the selected language
        // we're also flagging the current item with a css class here
        languages.map(lang => (
          <li className={selectedLanguage === lang ? 'selected' : ''} onClick={() => onLangSelect(lang)} key={lang}>
            {lang}
          </li>
        ))   
      )
    }
  </ul> 
</div>
  )
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.language-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
}

.language-menu li {
  padding: 1em;
}

.language-menu li:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

li.selected {
  background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

---

You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly. Doing so undercuts the entire point of React. Just emit the nodes you need. So instead of this:

```js
// don't do this. there's no need to manually create dom elements in react
[...props.ui.languages].forEach(function (language, i) {
  const el = document.createElement('li')
  el.value = language.languageCode
  el.innerHTML = language.name
  el.className = "item"
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
  })
  listContainer.appendChild(el)
})
```

Just emit the markup with jsx:

```
// within render method
[...props.ui.languages].map((language) => (
  <li key={language} onclick={...}>{language}</li>
))
```

---

When you do this:

```
// this sets onClick to undefined because openMenu doesn't return anything
onClick={openMenu(this)}
```

You're setting the `onclick` handler to the *return value* of `openMenu(this)`, which is `undefined` since `openMenu` doesn't return anything.

And again, don't manipulate the DOM. Instead of:

```js
e.parentElement.classList.add('open')
```

Use `setState` to track whether the menu is open or not:

```js
this.setState({open: true});
```

And then render accordingly:

```
const {open} = this.state;
<div className={open ? 'menu open' : 'menu'}>
 ...
</div>
```

(There are packages like [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) that can assist with composing classnames; I'm emitting `menu open` manually here to keep the example simple.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a few questions. This is not a class component, just a functional component. So where would I put the code to dynamically create the li's, if not in the render? Or (my lack of react knowledge might show here), should I just make this a class component? This will be rendered in a Main class component, so as far as I understand, when a component is being rendered in a class component, it should be functional.

Also- how does the setState portion change if I am using redux? This may be more of a design question. Should I set the open/close in global state?

Comment: You can do all of it in a functional component using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) like [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). The dynamically created `<li>` elements can be emitted directly within render if you want, or you can have a function that returns them. The state of the menu (opened/closed) should be isolated within the component itself, because that's the only thing concerned with it. It's the state of the component, not state of the application. I'll update my answer with a more comprehensive example.